# Javascript - measuring FPS and sync it with events

Tags: javascript, timer, synchronization

let's suppose I have a game loop like this

```
function update(){

myTime = Date.now() - myTime

// use myTime as you wish...


// reset myTime
myTime = Date.now()  

}
```

stuff happens there, ideally at 60fps but not always. Using Date.now() I need to know how many milliseconds happens between one frame and the other. Here's why:

I have a variable `X`, this variable should lineary increase so that every 1 second it is increased of 480 units. This increasing should be as smooth as possible so, I think, it should be of 0,48 every millisecond.

How can I do that considering that I just draw to the screen every 16,6 milliseconds (60fps)? Do I need to compensate that by adding 0,48 * 16,6 ? Or... what kind of forumla? I'm getting crazy on this, thanks in advance!

Comment: What engine are you running the game into? Pure JS?

Comment: yep, pure JS. It's a visual-music player I'm working on... 1 quarter in absolute midi time is 480 units. Easy to know, hard to let it work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the question, but maybe this will help?

To just get the time since the function last ran, you could do:

```
var lastTime = Date.now();

function update(){

    //do stuff here

    var myTime = Date.now(),
        timePassed = myTime - lastTime; //time passed since last time
    lastTime = Date.now(); //set for next time
}
```

​To see how many times the function runs each second you could do:

```
var lastTime = Date.now(), framerate=1;

function update(){

    //do stuff

    framerate++;
    if ((Date.now()-1000)>lastTime) { //if a second or more has passed
        console.log(framerate); //log number of times function has ran
        framerate=0;  //and reset values
        lastTime = Date.now();
    }
}
```

To join those functions, do:

```
var lastTimeEach = Date.now(), lastTimeSecond = Date.now(), framerate=1, x=480;

function update(){

    //do game logic

    var myTime = Date.now(), //time now
        timePassed = myTime - lastTimeEach; //time passed since last iteration
    lastTimeEach = Date.now(); //reset for next iteration

    framerate++;
    if ((myTime-1000)>lastTimeSecond) { //one second has passed
        x += 480; //add 480 to x
        framerate=0; //reset framerate
        lastTimeSecond = Date.now(); //reset for next second
    }
}​
```

Here's a [**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/De3ck/)

Comment: thanks! However I wanted to increase X lineary, as smooth as possible. Not just 480 in one shot every second but, for example, 480/1000 * numbers of ms passed since last frame. Hold on, I'm preparing a JSfiddle too...

Comment: here it is, one dot should be made every 1 second but they should also move at that constant speed... http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/EWhSw/

Comment: how, why isn't this perfectly syncing with my clock? In my script I don't use Math.round but myTime is always an integer number (usually around 17)

Comment: Most serverside or OS based timing functions are pretty accurate. Javascript on the other hand, not so much. Timers in Javascript are never going to get the exact time, there will always be some inacuracy. I have'nt tested the Date.now() function for accuracy, but I assume it's the same as other timed events. The lower you get the less accurate it is. If it's possible you could increment the x variable in an interval, but you'll probably still have to check and correct it every second or so.